# android 4.0. call log - securityexception

Tags: android

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
   CallLog.Calls._ID, 
   CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, 
   CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
   CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 
   CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
   CallLog.Calls.TYPE 
};

Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
       android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null
);
```

I want to get call logs to my application from the android call logs. Currently I have been working on android 4.0 version. I tried above code and it will generate the following exception.
What is the reason about this?
I have placed `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` permission tag to manifest file.

```
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phonelog/com.example.phonelog.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{41397ff8 3280:com.example.phonelog/u0a10053} (pid=3280, uid=10053) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{41397ff8 3280:com.example.phonelog/u0a10053} (pid=3280, uid=10053) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2530)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4460)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2002)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1101)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:356)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at com.example.phonelog.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-19 21:25:52.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3280):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the error trace says:

```
requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
```

You also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

to your list of permission uses in the AndroidManifest.

Of course,if you're only reading, you shouldn't also put the WRITE permission - READ will suffice.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` must be the correct answer.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>


Here are the permission i have written in the manifest file. Still jam getting the error. Any  hint????

Answer (score 0):

This error says, "I cannot read and write your received call logs, I need permissions for read and write the call logs from CallLogProvider", The CallLog provider contains information about placed and received calls.

Now that you should add **WRITE_CALL_LOG** permission to your manifest, if you got bug like this,

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{42931860 15578:com.hirecraft.jugunoo.passenger/u0a10095} (pid=15578, uid=10095) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Otherwise, You sholud add **READ_CALL_LOG** permission to your manifest, if you got bug like this,

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider uri content://call_log/calls from pid=16013, uid=10095 requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, or grantUriPermission()

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```